# How do you edit a globally scoped variable inside the component scope in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js

I want to edit the object property of a component based on the value that is returned from my API call. The problem is that the var that I use to set the object property is in the **global scope of the file** and the api call is being done inside the **component scope of the file**.

I have included codesandbox below. I want `variable` to change to "i have been changed"

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-glade-6zrsh?file=/pages/index.js:139-152

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

var variable = "not changed yet";

async function apiCall() {
  variable = await "i have been changed";
}

export default function TestComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      the variable value is:
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

TestComponent.variableValue = variable;
```

I realize that in order to change a globally scoped variable inside a function with JS you need to have the variable change asynchronously, but I don't know how to do that with React either.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you **sure** this is the best way to do this? Maybe context would be better if you're looking for component-component communication. Or lifting state up to a direct parent. But not this.

Comment: You are right. Normally I would use context or hoist the state up but in this case the app I'm working sets the component's layout based on the object's properties.

Comment: Would a root component state work with an effect to fetch? Then you can conditionally render different layouts.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why this needs to be external to React, but if it needs to be external and still trigger updates in React I would look at some sort of subscription base value. You could use an Observable or bake your own lightweight class if you don't need all the functionality. Once you had a subscribable value I would use a context to include it into React to obfuscate the fact that it is external everywhere else you need to use it.

Comment: Yeah after thinking about this over for a night it appears to be a state management issue. The reason why I am setting it as an objects property has to do with setting up persistent layouts in Next.js (https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/), but I think I will give hoisting the layout “state” up to the parent and then using a callback to change the parent state/layout from the child a shot. Usecontext might seems a little overkill for my problem though.